# How to access the ec2 instaces in a load balancer created using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I am creating an ASG which will have a classical load balancer . The desired number of instances is 5 , I am starting the asg creation using a userdata but even after experimenting multiple times the load balancer shows unhealthy hosts,i changed the subnet type of the vpc as public but the number of healthy host for the elb remains 0 .
Below is the code segment

```
 Vpc vpc=new Vpc(this,"MyVPC");
        AutoScalingGroup asg = AutoScalingGroup.Builder.create(this,"AutoScalingGroup").vpcSubnets(SubnetSelection.builder()
                        .subnetType(SubnetType.PUBLIC)
                        .build()).vpc(vpc).instanceType(InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, InstanceSize.MICRO))
                .machineImage(new AmazonLinuxImage()).minCapacity(1).desiredCapacity(5).maxCapacity(10).build();
        asg.addUserData("#!/bin/bash\n" +
                "# Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)\n" +
                "# install httpd (Linux 2 version)\n" +
                "yum update -y\n" +
                "yum install -y httpd\n" +
                "systemctl start httpd\n" +
                "systemctl enable httpd\n" +
                "echo \"<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>\" > /var/www/html/index.html");
        LoadBalancer loadbalancer=LoadBalancer.Builder.create(this,"ElasticLoadBalancer").vpc(vpc).internetFacing(Boolean.TRUE).healthCheck(software.amazon.awscdk.services.elasticloadbalancing.HealthCheck.builder().port(80).build())
                .build();
        loadbalancer.addTarget(asg);
        ListenerPort listenerPort = loadbalancer.addListener(LoadBalancerListener.builder().externalPort(80).build());
```

Also the instances those are created by default via ASG cannot be accessed on the web(by hitting their public IP) even after changing the security groups or making them all in a public subnet they are not accessible from instance connect.
Below is the list of ec2 present and the metrics for the elb
[This shows the list of EC2 instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoD3z.png) present ,[the metrics of elb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuqTz.png),motivation has been taken from the code present [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/java/classic-load-balancer)

Answer (score 0):

> not accessible from instance connect

Instance connect does not work in all instances by default. It must be properly [setup and configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html) to work, with specific security groups.

Comment: Tried everything still doesn't work .Do you have any idea why the ELB does not show up anything when it's dns is hit on the web (probably because the hosts are unhealthy but why so?)

Comment: @vbv2312 It depends on your setup. You haven't provide any details of your application nor how you configured the health checks.